# Maximum number of domains supported in Azure Websites

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

We're building a hosted service where each of our users gets a custom sub domain on our service's domain when they sign up (for example `john.myservice.com`).

We handled this by adding a wildcard entry in our Azure Website's domain manager (`*.myservice.com`) and Azure Websites would now correctly handle all sub domains of the domain we added.

However, we also allow our users to map their own custom domains to their sub domain (for example: `johnsmith.com` points to `john.myservice.com`).

Right now we've achieved this by adding an A Record to `johnsmith.com`'s DNS pointing to the Azure Websites IP Address, and have added `johnsmith.com` as an additional domain in Azure Websites' domain manager.

So far, this is working as expected. My question is how many such domains does Azure Websites support? Say we have a million users who each want to map their custom domains to their hosted sub domain.

**Does Azure have a hard limit on the number of fully qualified domains that can be mapped to a website?**

On a related note, what would be the best way to go about this on a Azure Website. I'm sure there are other approaches apart from the one we are using right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nir Mashkowski (Admin, Microsoft Azure) has stated that [the limit is now 500](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6986208-remove-the-limit-of-the-custom-domain-names-in-azu) on the Azure feedback forums.

Comment: "On a related note, what would be the best way to go about this on a Azure Website. I'm sure there are other approaches apart from the one we are using right now." Anyone have any better suggestions for this? Which solution did you end up going with Uzair? Regards

Comment: Does anyone know what approach to take if you need more like 5000 hostnames?

Comment: As this answer is a few years old - i thought I would ask - is there any hint / roadmap of increasing this limit?  Although 500 is fairly ample, we are trying to plan a scalable infrastructure for a multi-tenanted site - so

Comment: @William You're best off asking MS about this or posting on their feedback portal - https://feedback.azure.com/

Comment: @Mr.Flibble - I'd suggest getting a VM instead of using the Websites/App Service.

Comment: Looks like limit is still in place: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b0011f01-999f-42f5-a0a4-6db963e694a1/whats-the-limit-on-number-of-custom-domains-that-can-be-mapped-with-azure-traffic-manager?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 5):

Azure Websites has a hard limit of 250 custom domains per site.

Comment: 250 was the correct answer at the time. However, they've recently updated the limit as per @Peter Baily's answer below.